# How to make text layer animator expression to change regardless of layer position on timeline

Tags: javascript, expression, after-effects

With the help of chatgpt and hours of searching I've got an expression that would change range selector's offset based on lenght of a text layer. It works as intended, but when I move the layer offset value stops changing. in short it only works at the beginning of timeline.

My question is how can I make it work, so for example if I move text layer on timeline offset value would switch back to 0 and gradually increase based on text layer length

Here's current script

```
words = text.sourceText.split(" ").length;
offsetMax = words;
layerDuration = thisLayer.outPoint - thisLayer.inPoint;

Math.floor(linear(time, 0, layerDuration, 0, offsetMax));
```

I tried asking chatgpt for answer, and it gave me this

```
words = text.sourceText.split(" ").length;
offsetMax = words;
compDuration = thisComp.duration;

linear(time, 0, compDuration, 0, offsetMax * compDuration);
```

but it's not what I want